# How to set the js attributes defined in index.html from Flutter Code for Flutter-Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

So I am Implementing the RazorPay Payment Gateway in my Flutter Web Project. The Payment Gateway was implemented successfully. But my question is how we can set the Javascript attributes defined in the index.html file .

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="razorpay_payment_with_flutter">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>razorpay_payment_with_flutter</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
  <script>

       var options = {
         "key": "my-api-key",
          "amount": "10000", "currency": "INR",
          "name": "Aniket Ambore",
          "description": "Just a flutter web project",
          "image": "https://i.ibb.co/BCwcPzN/Pngtree-flat-lay-home-office-concept-4341518.jpg",
          "handler": function (response){
             window.parent.postMessage("SUCCESS","*");      //2
             alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
             alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
             alert(response.razorpay_signature)
          },
          "prefill": {
             "name": "",
             "email": "",
             "contact": ""
           },
           "notes": {
             "address": "Autofy"
          },
          "theme": {
             "color": "#DF0145"
          },
          "modal": {
            "ondismiss": function(){
               window.parent.postMessage("MODAL_CLOSED","*");   //3
            }
          }
       };

       var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
       window.onload = function(e){  //1
          rzp1.open();
          e.preventDefault();
       }

     </script>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is the small snippet of my updated **index.html** . And how can we set the **key** of the **var options** map from my flutter project.
Like suppose if I want to change the value of the **amount**, How can I pass it from my **dart file** to **index.html** .

---

My flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.21.0-9.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1304], locale en-IN)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

---

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="razorpay_payment_with_flutter">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>razorpay_payment_with_flutter</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
  <script>

       var options = {
         "key": "my-api-key",
          "amount": "10000", "currency": "INR",
          "name": "Aniket Ambore",
          "description": "Just a flutter web project",
          "image": "https://i.ibb.co/BCwcPzN/Pngtree-flat-lay-home-office-concept-4341518.jpg",
          "handler": function (response){
             window.parent.postMessage("SUCCESS","*");      //2
             alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
             alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
             alert(response.razorpay_signature)
          },
          "prefill": {
             "name": "",
             "email": "",
             "contact": ""
           },
           "notes": {
             "address": "Autofy"
          },
          "theme": {
             "color": "#DF0145"
          },
          "modal": {
            "ondismiss": function(){
               window.parent.postMessage("MODAL_CLOSED","*");   //3
            }
          }
       };

       var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
       window.onload = function(e){  //1
          rzp1.open();
          e.preventDefault();
       }

     </script>
  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

razorpay_web.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'ui_fake.dart' if (dart.library.html) 'dart:ui' as ui;

class RazorPayWeb extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //register view factory
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory("rzp-html",(int viewId) {
      IFrameElement element=IFrameElement();
      //Event Listener
      window.onMessage.forEach((element) {
        print('---------------------------Event Received in callback: ${element.data}');
        if(element.data=='MODAL_CLOSED'){
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }else if(element.data=='SUCCESS'){
          print('PAYMENT SUCCESSFULL!!!!!!!');
        }
      });

    element.requestFullscreen();
    //element.src='assets/html/payment.html';
    element.style.border = 'none';
    return element;
  });

    return Scaffold(
        body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'rzp-html'),
          );
        }));
  }
}
```

---

ui_fake.dart

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

// ignore: camel_case_types
class platformViewRegistry {
  static registerViewFactory(String viewId, dynamic cb) {
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(viewId, cb);
  }
}
```

---

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:razorpay_flutter/razorpay_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:razorpay_payment_with_flutter/WebImplementation/razorpay_web.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        // This makes the visual density adapt to the platform that you run
        // the app on. For desktop platforms, the controls will be smaller and
        // closer together (more dense) than on mobile platforms.
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: RazorPayWeb(),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Also The code does not deals with the `razorpay_flutter` plugin because it was not suitable for Flutter_Web .

Answer (score 0):

Use [`srddoc`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/IFrameElement/srcdoc.html) property, instead of [`src`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/IFrameElement/src.html) property of `IFrameElement` object to pass your entire HTML content. You can combine string interpolation to pass the attributes.

Here is an example:

```
//register view factory
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory("rzp-html",(int viewId) {
      IFrameElement element=IFrameElement();
      //Event Listener
      window.onMessage.forEach((element) {
        print('---------------------------Event Received in callback: ${element.data}');
        if(element.data=='MODAL_CLOSED'){
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }else if(element.data=='SUCCESS'){
          print('PAYMENT SUCCESSFULL!!!!!!!');
        }
      });

    element.requestFullscreen();
    // ****************** change you need to make *************
    element.srcdoc = '<html><p>Your entire HTML content with an ${attribute}</p></html>';
    element.style.border = 'none';
    return element;
  });
```